# Swap usdt to etherium error

Tags: failed-transaction, usdt

i am new to this site and i am glad i found it, hopefully someone can help me.
So this morning i tries to swap some usdt to etherium, but i didnt go through, i got to error messages and four different fees, my wallet it's showing 0 balance so I don't know where it went. Here is the transaction and hope someone can help me.

Thanks!!!

transaction hash: 0x4634a153793b58d270233b7e80b75e3ff96d2ba39b80e56e6fb8df71e166ed89

Contract: 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the transactions at [your address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5d7396829f00de512b564cb79f234340a65808ab), I see that you attempted to make the same swap 3 times. The first one was successful in exchanging your USDT to ETH. The two other failed, as expected, because you did not have any USDT left. Did you send the swap multiple times?

You actually spent all your ETH to pay the transaction fees for those 3 swaps. Failed transactions also incur fees because miners have to process your transaction even if it fails.